# How to select best control series among many for comparion?

Tags: regression, time-series, sampling, matching, treatment-effect

I want to analyse the effect of a treatment on certain individuals. To make it more clear, here is the context:

- There are a few individuals that are going to partake in a certain treatment soon
- There are more than 200 other individuals that may serve as controls
- Each individual has a time series that consists of 22 observations

What I want to do is: for each one of the soon-to-be treated series, select the X individuals (series) from the 200 possible controls that mostly resembles the soon-to-be treated one. I've tried computing the R2 for each of the candidates and ranking them in terms of best fit, but I'm not sure if the result is that good.

Is there any other approach I can try? Don't know if clustering would do it, or if there's some other way that better suits time series.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you not want to use all 200+ of them?

Comment: The method of synthetic control was specifically designed for this scenario.

Comment: @mdewey it's very costly, so we can only gonna be able to keep track of a few of them

Comment: @Noah I've used synthetic controle before, but here there aren't any X variables for each individual, only the outcome variable. Maybe I can use a few lags?